# send different amount of tokens to different accounts in single transaction

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.token

```
void token::transferfee( name from, name to, asset quantity,const string& memo) {
action(
    permission_level{from, "active"_n},
    "eosuperadmin"_n,
    "transfer"_n,
    std::make_tuple(from, to, quantity,string("FEE"))
).send() ;}

void token::transfer( const name& from,const name& to,const asset& quantity,const string& memo){
check( from != to, "cannot transfer to self" );
require_auth( from );
check( is_account( to ), "to account does not exist");
auto sym = quantity.symbol.code();
stats statstable( get_self(), sym.raw() );
const auto& st = statstable.get( sym.raw() );
require_recipient( from );
require_recipient( to );
check( quantity.is_valid(), "invalid quantity" );
check( quantity.amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity" );
check( quantity.symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch" );
check( memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes" );
auto payer = has_auth( to ) ? to : from;
if(memo == string("FEE")){
  sub_balance( from, quantity ); 
  add_balance( to, quantity, payer ); 
  }
else{
const float eosuperadmin_fee= (float(quantity.amount)/PERCISION)*EOSUPERADMIN; 
const float eoswallettik_fee= (float(quantity.amount)/PERCISION)*EOSWALLETTIK; 
const float forcharities_fee= (float(quantity.amount)/PERCISION)*FORCHARITIES; 
const asset eosuperadmin_fee_asset = asset{static_cast<int64_t>(eosuperadmin_fee * PERCISION),quantity.symbol}; 
const asset eoswallettik_fee_asset = asset{static_cast<int64_t>(eoswallettik_fee * PERCISION),quantity.symbol}; 
const asset forcharities_fee_asset = asset{static_cast<int64_t>(forcharities_fee * PERCISION),quantity.symbol}; 
const asset newQuantity = quantity - (eosuperadmin_fee_asset + eoswallettik_fee_asset + forcharities_fee_asset); 
check( eosuperadmin_fee_asset.is_valid(), "invalid fees" );
check( eoswallettik_fee_asset.is_valid(), "invalid fees" );
check( forcharities_fee_asset.is_valid(), "invalid fees" );

sub_balance( from, newQuantity );
add_balance( to, newQuantity, payer );
if( eosuperadmin_fee_asset.amount > 0 && from != name("eosuperadmin"))
  transferfee(from,name("eosuperadmin"),eosuperadmin_fee_asset,string("0.0003% transfer-fee"));
if( eoswallettik_fee_asset.amount > 0 && from != name("eoswallettik"))
  transferfee(from,name("eoswallettik"),eoswallettik_fee_asset,string("0.0001% transfer-fee"));      
if( forcharities_fee_asset.amount > 0 && from != name("forcharities"))
  transferfee(from,name("forcharities"),forcharities_fee_asset,string("0.0001% transfer-fee"));      
}
}
```

This code is working on jungle testnet but not working on eos mainnet.I also have set the eosio.code permission but still not working.

**eosuperadmin permission**
[image]

**eoswallettik permission**

[image]

**forcharities permission**

[image]

**Transfer result on testnet**
[image]

**Mainnet Transfer result**
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you edit your answer to show the permissions structure for each of the accounts involved in your code?

Comment: Now I update the question

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say for sure what the problem is without seeing the error message.

It looks like you are trying to transfer money from the `from` account to the `to` account with the permission of `eosuperadmin@eosio.code`, which isn't possible because the transfer function of `eosuperadmin` requires the authorization of `from`.
You can bypass this in two ways:

1. Change `require_auth(from)` in `token::transfer` to `eosio::check(has_auth(from) || has_auth(get_self()), "Missing required authority")`. Also change the inline action in `transferfee` to use `get_self()` instead of `from`.
2. Add the `eosuperadmin@eosio.code` permission to the `from` account's active permission

Comment: I want to deduct fee on every transfer and distribute the fees in three different accounts

Comment: I understand the goal, you just need to ideally add the error message. In any case the problem with permissions is still valid I think

Comment: Ok let me try your changes

Comment: If it works, be sure to upvote and accept the answer to help others who have the same problem

Comment: Now its giving this warning
"Transaction is not authorized by from_account".
on jungle testnet.
But still its not working for multiple transfers.
And not working on mainnet.

Comment: Did you try method 1 above? If you did it properly it should work, maybe you can post the updated code as an edit to your original question and if you missed something I can point it out to you there

Answer (score 0):

```
void token::transfer(const name &from, const name &to, const asset &quantity, const string &memo){
check(from != to, "cannot transfer to self");
require_auth(from);
//check(has_auth(from) || has_auth(get_self()),"Missing required authority");
check(is_account(to), "to account does not exist");
auto sym = quantity.symbol.code();
stats statstable(get_self(), sym.raw());
const auto &st = statstable.get(sym.raw());
require_recipient(from);
require_recipient(to);
check(quantity.is_valid(), "invalid quantity");
check(quantity.amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity");
check(quantity.symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch");
check(memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes");
auto payer = has_auth(to) ? to : from;
const float eosuperadmin_fee = (float(quantity.amount) / PRECISION) * EOSUPERADMIN;
const float eoswallettik_fee = (float(quantity.amount) / PRECISION) * EOSWALLETTIK;
const float forcharities_fee = (float(quantity.amount) / PRECISION) * FORCHARITIES;
const asset eosuperadmin_fee_asset = asset{static_cast<int64_t>(eosuperadmin_fee * PRECISION), quantity.symbol};
const asset eoswallettik_fee_asset = asset{static_cast<int64_t>(eoswallettik_fee * PRECISION), quantity.symbol};
const asset forcharities_fee_asset = asset{static_cast<int64_t>(forcharities_fee * PRECISION), quantity.symbol};
const asset newQuantity = quantity - (eosuperadmin_fee_asset + eoswallettik_fee_asset + forcharities_fee_asset);
check(eosuperadmin_fee_asset.is_valid(), "invalid fees");
check(eoswallettik_fee_asset.is_valid(), "invalid fees");
check(forcharities_fee_asset.is_valid(), "invalid fees");

sub_balance(from, newQuantity);
add_balance(to, newQuantity, payer);

if (eosuperadmin_fee_asset.amount > 0 && from != name("eoswallettik"))
{
    add_balance(name("eosuperadmin"), eosuperadmin_fee_asset, payer);
    fee_summary(name("eosuperadmin"), std::to_string(static_cast<float>(eosuperadmin_fee_asset.amount) / static_cast<float>(PRECISION)));
}
if (eoswallettik_fee_asset.amount > 0 && from != name("eoswallettik"))
{
    add_balance(name("eoswallettik"), eoswallettik_fee_asset, payer);
    fee_summary(name("eoswallettik"), std::to_string(static_cast<float>(eoswallettik_fee_asset.amount) / static_cast<float>(PRECISION)));
}
if (forcharities_fee_asset.amount > 0 && from != name("forcharities"))
{
    add_balance(name("forcharities"), forcharities_fee_asset, payer);
    fee_summary(name("forcharities"), std::to_string(static_cast<float>(forcharities_fee_asset.amount) / static_cast<float>(PRECISION)));
}
}
```

**Add Anther Action Method**

```
void token::notify(name user, string fee){
require_auth(get_self());
require_recipient(user);
}
```

**Add private helper method in .hpp**

```
void fee_summary(name from, string fee){
        action(
           permission_level{get_self(),"active"_n},
           get_self(),
           "notify"_n,
           std::make_tuple(from, fee + " TIK")
        ).send();
     }
```